# Weird bug with gorhom/modal-sheet in iOS 16.x

Tags: ios, react-native

Whenever the modal sheet is active and i try to minimize the app (get it to background) the app crashes (i will provide crash log below)
This does not happen if while active the modal has a device keyboard active too.
Note that while my use-case has some other UIs too in the modal, i tried this with a clean modal (only a flex View inside) and the bug still occurs

Crash Log:

```
Incident Identifier: 197F4045-FE91-4A5C-AAD6-67A1FE45F6DE
CrashReporter Key: AFAC9E2B-67F8-B2EC-4DC5-14ACE972736F
Hardware Model: Macmini8,1
Process: myApp [30530]
Path: .../myApp.app/myApp
Identifier: com.myApp.myApp
Version: 1.7.41 (52)
Code Type: X86-64 (Native)
Role: Foreground
Parent Process: launchd_sim [1097]
Coalition: com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.9A1E865F-E79D-43C4-B1E4-C8CEB1CD041C [971]
Responsible Process: SimulatorTrampoline [1050]

Date/Time: 2023-06-19 14:44:55.7056 +0300
Launch Time: 2023-06-19 14:44:41.8532 +0300
OS Version: macOS 13.2 (22D49)
Release Type: User
Report Version: 104

Exception Type: EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread: 0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0 CoreFoundation 0x7ff80042889b __exceptionPreprocess + 226
1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x7ff80004dba3 objc_exception_throw + 48
2 CoreFoundation 0x7ff800437ab8 +[NSObject(NSObject) instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:] + 0
3 CoreFoundation 0x7ff80042cd71 forwarding + 1431
4 CoreFoundation 0x7ff80042f068 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5 myApp 0x10607c571 -[InteractableView gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:] + 65 (InteractableView.m:346)
6 UIKitCore 0x11a4d49cc -[UIGestureRecognizer _shouldBegin] + 241
7 UIKitCore 0x11a4ce4c1 -[UIGestureRecognizer setState:] + 296
8 UIKitCore 0x11a4f843d -[_UISystemGestureGateGestureRecognizer _systemGestureStateChanged:] + 343
9 CoreFoundation 0x7ff80035964b CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER + 137
10 CoreFoundation 0x7ff800359581 ___CFXRegistrationPost_block_invoke + 86
11 CoreFoundation 0x7ff800358b60 _CFXRegistrationPost + 541
12 CoreFoundation 0x7ff800358469 _CFXNotificationPost + 822
13 Foundation 0x7ff800c09459 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 82
14 UIKitCore 0x11ab21cb2 -[UIWindow _setSystemGestureRecognitionIsPossible:andTouchesAreCancelled:] + 220
15 UIKitCore 0x11ab8f59d __updateSystemGestureRecognitionIsPossible + 354
16 UIKitCore 0x11ab9132e __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 3954
17 UIKitCore 0x11ab94f69 __processEventQueue + 8334
18 UIKitCore 0x11ab8b2a1 __eventFetcherSourceCallback + 272
19 CoreFoundation 0x7ff800387fe5 CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION + 17
20 CoreFoundation 0x7ff800387f24 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 157
21 CoreFoundation 0x7ff800387781 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 308
22 CoreFoundation 0x7ff800381e23 __CFRunLoopRun + 927
23 CoreFoundation 0x7ff8003816a7 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 560
24 GraphicsServices 0x7ff809cb128a GSEventRunModal + 139
25 UIKitCore 0x11aac8ad3 -[UIApplication _run] + 994
26 UIKitCore 0x11aacd9ef UIApplicationMain + 123
27 myApp 0x105c02f88 main + 104 (main.m:8)
28 dyld_sim 0x10a2182bf start_sim + 10
29 dyld 0x10db6a310 start + 2432

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x7ff83611d22a __pthread_kill + 10
1 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x7ff836175f7b pthread_kill + 263
2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x7ff800132fe0 abort + 130
3 libc++abi.dylib 0x7ff800258742 abort_message + 241
4 libc++abi.dylib 0x7ff80024995d demangling_terminate_handler() + 266
5 libobjc.A.dylib 0x7ff800032082 _objc_terminate() + 96
6 libc++abi.dylib 0x7ff800257b65 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 8
7 libc++abi.dylib 0x7ff80025a3a4 __cxa_rethrow + 99
8 libobjc.A.dylib 0x7ff80004dd0d objc_exception_rethrow + 37
9 CoreFoundation 0x7ff800381769 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 754
10 GraphicsServices 0x7ff809cb128a GSEventRunModal + 139
11 UIKitCore 0x11aac8ad3 -[UIApplication _run] + 994
12 UIKitCore 0x11aacd9ef UIApplicationMain + 123
13 myApp 0x105c02f88 main + 104 (main.m:8)
14 dyld_sim 0x10a2182bf start_sim + 10
15 dyld 0x10db6a310 start + 2432

Thread 1:
0 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x7ff836171c58 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x7ff836171c58 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x7ff836171c58 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4:: com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x7ff8361165c2 mach_msg2_trap + 10
1 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x7ff836124604 mach_msg2_internal + 82
2 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x7ff83611d635 mach_msg_overwrite + 723
3 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x7ff8361168a8 mach_msg + 19
4 CoreFoundation 0x7ff80038788e __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 145
5 CoreFoundation 0x7ff800381fdf __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
6 CoreFoundation 0x7ff8003816a7 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 560
7 Foundation 0x7ff800c568b4 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 213
8 Foundation 0x7ff800c56b2d -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 72
9 UIKitCore 0x11ab9e286 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 535
10 Foundation 0x7ff800c8011b NSThread__start + 1009
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x7ff836176259 _pthread_start + 125
12 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x7ff836171c7b thread_start + 15

Thread 5:
0 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x7ff836171c58 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6:
0 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x7ff836171c58 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 7:: com.facebook.react.JavaScript
0 hermes 0x10ab7c050 0x10ab32000 + 303184
1 hermes 0x10ab79753 0x10ab32000 + 292691
2 hermes 0x10ab59714 0x10ab32000 + 161556
3 hermes 0x10ab58f42 0x10ab32000 + 159554
4 hermes 0x10ab7a580 0x10ab32000 + 296320
5 hermes 0x10ab79753 0x10ab32000 + 292691
6 hermes 0x10ab59714 0x10ab32000 + 161556
7 hermes 0x10ab58f42 0x10ab32000 + 159554
8 hermes 0x10ab7a580 0x10ab32000 + 296320
9 hermes 0x10ab79753 0x10ab32000 + 292691
10 hermes 0x10ab59714 0x10ab32000 + 161556
11 hermes 0x10ab57459 0x10ab32000 + 152665
12 hermes 0x10abfc1cb 0x10ab32000 + 827851
13 hermes 0x10ab5948e 0x10ab32000 + 160910
14 hermes 0x10ab7a55d 0x10ab32000 + 296285
15 hermes 0x10ab79753 0x10ab32000 + 292691
16 hermes 0x10ab59714 0x10ab32000 + 161556
17 hermes 0x10ab57c98 0x10ab32000 + 154776
18 hermes 0x10ac49206 0x10ab32000 + 1143302
19 hermes 0x10ab5948e 0x10ab32000 + 160910
20 hermes 0x10ab7a55d 0x10ab32000 + 296285
21 hermes 0x10ab79753 0x10ab32000 + 292691
22 hermes 0x10ab59714 0x10ab32000 + 161556
23 hermes 0x10ab57c98 0x10ab32000 + 154776
24 hermes 0x10ac49206 0x10ab32000 + 1143302
25 hermes 0x10ab5948e 0x10ab32000 + 160910
26 hermes 0x10ab7a55d 0x10ab32000 + 296285
27 hermes 0x10ab79753 0x10ab32000 + 292691
28 hermes 0x10ab59714 0x10ab32000 + 161556
29 hermes 0x10ab58f42 0x10ab32000 + 159554
30 hermes 0x10ab3bbb3 0x10ab32000 + 39859
31 myApp 0x106542dcb facebook::jsi::RuntimeDecorator<facebook::jsi::Runtime
```

Environment info
@gorhom/bottom-sheet 4.4.5
react-native  0.70.5
react-native-reanimated 3.0.2
react-native-gesture-handler 2.8.0
(Note: I have tried various version combinations with RN-reanimated 2.x RN-gesture-handler 2.9.0 and odler/newer versions of your modal-sheet, but no solutions whatsoever)

I understand the issue might not be related directly to bottom-sheet, but it only happens while bottom-sheet modal is active and without an active device keyboard and in iOS 16.x devices, so this is why i decided to ask for your help here

Steps To Reproduce
While a modal sheet is open in an ios 16.x device and with no device keyboard active, try to minimize the app and drag it to the background

Any kind of help regarding the crash will be appreciated

The app is working fine in 15.x iOS devices, and happens only on iOS 16.x